# Unfortunately charity App has stopped. How to fix this issue?

Tags: java, android, firebase, ionic-framework

I am working in ionic framework and trying to deploy application for android using android studio. I am beginner in android studio. when I deployed the app I got the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.R$string
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.StringResourceValueReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:156)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:244)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4792)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4327)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code in build.gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

apply from: "variables.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I update `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'` also but still getting same error.
How can I resolve this problem. please help me.

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out? I'm running into the same error... it's not helpful.

Comment: Actually I was trying to deploy ionic app using capacitor and found that error during deploying through android studio. But now I use cordova which work for me.